# Put a new prestashop under a prestashop, the url is not working. backend office works perfoect

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I currently have prestashop running on the server. Then a uploaded a new one with new folder under the old one the structure would be like this

`\-- root folder
    |-- folder for the old prestashop
    |-- folder for the old prestashop
    |-- folder for the old prestashop
    |-- folder for the old prestashop
    |-- folder for the old prestashop
    |-- new prestashop folder
    |   -- folder for the new prestashop
    |   -- folder for the new prestashop
    |   -- folder for the new prestashop
    |   -- folder for the new prestashop`

I put the two prestashops table into one database with different prefix, so they will not mix up.

I also changed the settings.inc.php database users and password and the prefix of course. I changed the

`shop_url table:
domain: current domain
domain_ssl: current doamin
physical_uri: folder name for the new prestashop`

This setting will take me to the old prerstashop front page.
I can still go to the backed office of the new prestashop.

I also tried to set the virtual_uri to the folder name for the new prestashop. still not working.

Why? Did I miss something?

prestashop version: 1.6.1.7

Thanks for you help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried regenerating the .htaccess file in your second store's root folder ?

You can regenerate the .htaccess file by clicking the save button in the "Seo & URLs" menu.